# Optimize performance of a equal method to mark multiple rows in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, equals

I've the following method:

```
private void SelectingCoreItems(SortedList<ICoreItem, ICoreItem> sortedList)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisibleCoreItems.Count; i++)
    {
        CoreItem currentItem = VisibleCoreItems[i];

        if (sortedList.ContainsKey(currentItem))
        {
            itemListView.SelectedItems.Add(currentItem);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to mark all equal items. That works, but the performance is very bad because the sortedList contains 10,000 items and the VisibleCoreItems over 200,000 items.

Is there a way to optimize the method?

Comment: Side note: consider reading about each of basic [collections types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.Generic%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN as each collection type's description includes "performance consideration" section like [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). This will let you pick most suitable collection for many cases.

Comment: `SortedList` is basically never the correct collection for any situation, ever.  There is *always* a better collection to use.  Just pretend that it doesn't exist and your life will be easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `HashSet<ICoreItem>` instead of `SortedList<ICoreItem, ICoreItem>`:

```
private void SelectingCoreItems(SortedList<ICoreItem, ICoreItem> sortedList)
{
    var lookup = new HashSet<ICoreItem>(sortedList.Select(i => i.Key));
    for (int i = 0; i < VisibleCoreItems.Count; i++)
    {
        CoreItem currentItem = VisibleCoreItems[i];

        if (lookup.Contains(currentItem))
        {
            itemListView.SelectedItems.Add(currentItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, it may be slow to compare instances of `ICoreItem` interface (depending on implementation). If they contain property that is unique for elements in `sortedList` (for example, `Id`), it may be worth to use this property for `lookup` set.

**EDIT**. If elements of `sortedList` do not have reasonable `GetHashCode` and `Equals` implementation you may also need to specify `IEqualityComparer<ICoreItem>` as second argument to `HashSet` constructor.

Comment: Yes, [SortedList.ContainsKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms132332.aspx) is `O(log n)` while [HashSet.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb356440.aspx) is `O(1)`.

Comment: Also, maybe provide a specific [IEqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms132151.aspx)